# For each positive integer n > 2 is there a "perfect" n-cubed n-cube?

Tags: combinatorics

Roland Sprague found the first "perfect" squared square.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square
For each positive integer n > 3, is there an analogous "perfect" hypercubing of the hypercube in dimension n?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube

Comment: There's a little confusion between the subject line ($n\gt 2$) and the body of the Question ($n\gt 3$).  The material in the Wikipedia article, recited in the one Answer so far, may be familiar to you, but you might want to clarify if you don't accept the argument that the failure for $n=3$ implies further failures for larger $n$.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square):

"Unlike the case of squaring the square, a hard but solvable problem, cubing the cube is impossible. This can be shown by a relatively simple argument. Consider a hypothetical cubed cube. The bottom face of this cube is a squared square; lift off the rest of the cube, so you have a square region of the plane covered with a collection of cubes.

Consider the smallest cube in this collection, with side c (call it S). Since the smallest square of a squared square cannot be on its edge, its neighbours will all tower over it, meaning that there isn't space to put a cube of side larger than c on top of it. Since the construction is a cubed cube, you're not allowed to use a cube of side equal to c; so only smaller cubes may stand upon S. This means that the top face of S must be a squared square, and the argument continues by infinite descent. Thus it is not possible to dissect a cube into finitely many smaller cubes of different sizes.

Similarly, it is impossible to hypercube a hypercube, because each cell of the hypercube would need to be a cubed cube, and so on into the higher dimensions."